# UICollectionViewCell with button/UIView inside requires 2 taps - [iOS]

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell with a button/UIView inside of it.

It requires 2 taps to execute a view with TapGestureRecognizer:

```
singleTapBG.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
self.btnSubmit.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.btnSubmit addGestureRecognizer:singleTapBG];
```

Comment: it is because collection view cell has a scroll view and tey way you give single tap may interfere with the touch to scroll view. You shouldn't give tap gesture, instead you should use a button in a view that doesn't have any tap gestures.

Comment: Replacing the view with a button had the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Remove the gesture recognizer and add a target to your button.  This should solve the 2 taps issue and only require one.

```
self.btnSubmit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myClass.pressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Hmmm, try to also disable selections within the collectionView...  collectionView.allowsSelection = false